# Word meaning the arrangement of sounds or syllables to form words?

Tags: syntax, language-agnostic, linguistics, construct

See Title.
An answer would also satisfy:
Syntax is to Sentence as ______ is to Word?
Or, in more code-friendly terms
Syntax is to Function Logic as ______ is to Construct Logic? (idk, I tried)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [**phonotactics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics).

Comment: A more appropriate word is phonology. The example given by the OP seems to refer to Grammar which is made up of syntax, morphology and phonology. Phonotactics is one aspect of phonology just as punctuation is one aspect of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to your question depending on your exact intent. If I were to guess, the word you're looking for is: [morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)) but it could also be [phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology). However, I don't think "phonology" fits your second example.

The thing you seem to be describing are various parts of [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar). Grammar is the study of [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax), phonology and morphology.

Syntax describes the general structure of the language. How words fit together.

Phonology describes how sounds fit together in the language. How many vowels there are, the consonants, the types of consonants etc.

Morphology describes how words are formed in the language. Does the language modify words with tenses? Does the language modify words with gender? Does the language not modify words at all but instead use other words? etc.